# PHP How to output a string that comes after a certain keyword in a long text

Tags: php, delimiter

Basically, I want to take a long text file (source code), find a specific keyword in that file, and then print out the next 400 characters that come after that keyword.  I don't want every thing after the keyword because that ends up being  20,000+ characters.
If I could, I'd like to delimit them right there (which is what I tried to do originally but failed) It's becoming very confusing very quickly. If I can just get the 400 characters, then I can save that to a text file, and then delimit that 400 character text file.

My code now is:

```
        <?php
            $website = $_GET["website"]; //I'm pulling the website from a form
            $contents = file_get_contents($website));
            $del = 'keyword'; 
            $search = preg_quote($del, '/');
            $search = "/^.*$search.*\$/m";
            if(preg_match_all($search, $contents, $found)){
                echo implode("\n", $found[0]);
            }else{}
        ?>
```

The problem is the above prints out EVERYthing after the keyword, and I can't even take what I get and delimit it further. I'm at the point where the more I come up with ideas the further I'm getting from the solution.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: is that source code HTML or XML?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `substr($your_string, 0, 400)` to get only 400 characters starting from string.

Syntax for using this method is `substr(string,start,length)`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a combination of `strpos`, `strlen` and `substr`. You don't need any regex to do this, and you should not use it because regex generally is slow as death. Avoid regex whenever possible, and only use it when you don't have any other answer.

```
<?php
$website = $_GET["website"]; //I'm pulling the website from a form
$contents = file_get_contents($website));
$del = 'keyword';

//get the index of the end of your split value
//this is the character index of your keyword, plus the length of the keyword,
//so it will start collecting the next bit at the end of the first occurance of keyword.
$index = strpos($contents, $del) + strlen($del);

//get the text you want
$text = substr($contents, $index, 400);
```